# Getting data into highcharts stacked bar from an array

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having quite a bit of trouble getting data into a highchart.

I want my chart to look like [this](https://codepen.io/GeorgeBT/pen/pQYXyw)

But rather than adding the data in like this:

```
series: [{
    data: [5]
  }, {
    data: [2]
  }, {
    data: [9]
  }]
```

I have an array containing the values: `var array = [5, 2, 9]`

I've tried:

```
series: [{
    data: array
},
```

and

```
series: [{
    data: JSON.parse(array)
},
```

and also a for loop to wrap around the series and for each item in the it to the data: for highcharts but it doesn't work. I know its quite a beginners question but I'm struggling to work out how to do it.

Many thanks in advance for your help,

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this mate**

```js
let arr = [5, 2, 9]
let objTemp = arr.reduce((output,current)=>{
  output.push({data : [current]})
  return output;
},[])
let finalObj = {
  series : objTemp
}

console.log(finalObj)
```

Comment: Works a treat! Cheers for your help!